# Why "new EventHandler(Handler)" in .Net?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, event-handling

In VisualStudio 2008 and 2010, when I type, e.g.

```
this.Activated +=
```

and press Tab, VisualStudio automatically complements the line:

```
this.Activated += new EventHandler(MainWindow_Activated);
```

But the simpler, more laconic versions works too:

```
this.Activated += MainWindow_Activated;
```

Are these lines equivalent? `new EventHandler` is probably there for a reason...

Comment: This question might have been asked and answered already. I searched and didn't succeed.

Comment: You don't need the "new" on the second way, either. In fact, that doesn't compile.

Comment: *"new EventHandler is probably there for a reason"* - backwards compatibility.  The latter syntax is newer.

Comment: They are equivalent. In your 2nd example (without the `new`), the delegate type is inferred.

Comment: ReSharper always tells me to remove the `new EventHandler`.

Comment: @Matt H: thanks, I've just corrected the typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer versions of C# infer the long version when you use the short version.  This means even though you write less code, it still compiles to the longer version.

Answer (score 3):

Jon Skeet wrote in [his Refcard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/csharp):

> C# 2
>
> C# 2 introduced two important
>   improvements in the ways we can create
>   delegate instances.
>
> 1. You no longer
>      need the new delegate-type part:
>
> `StringPredicate  predicate   =   fveCharacters.Filter;`

meaning as of C# 2, you can use the above instead of

`StringPredicate predicate = new    StringPredicate(fveCharacters.Filter);`

So I'm guessing Visual Studio puts it there for backwards-compatibility.